# I want to show total work hours with minutes in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show total work hours with minutes in SQL query

```
select 
  mom.machinery_operation_master_id,
  mom.assigned_code,
  mom.record_type,
  (case when mom.record_type=1 then time(mom.entered_time) end) power_on_time,
  (case when mom.record_type=2 then time(mom.entered_time) end) power_off_time,
  (case when mom.record_type=3 then time(mom.entered_time) end) breakdown_time,
  (case when mom.record_type=4 then time(mom.entered_time) end) repaired_time  
from machinery_operation_master mom 
where mom.location_id = '9' and 
      mom.created_at between '2019-09-17 08:00:00' and '2019-09-18 07:59:00'
```

suppose power on time : 13:00:00 in 1st row and in second row power off time : 14:30:00, then that my expected output should be like this. total hours with minutes : 1:30:00

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Add your table description

Comment: Sample data and expected output

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. But first take a look at [mcve].

Comment: im using my work bench 6.3

Comment: suppose power on time : 13:00:00 in 1st row and  in second row power off time : 14:30:00, then that my expected output should be like this. total hours with minutes : 1:30:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using mariadb: result is `HH:mm`

```
select concat((TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, t1.power_on_time, t1.power_off_time) 
            - TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, t1.breakdown_time, t1.repaired_time))/3600, ':',
                ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.power_on_time, t1.power_off_time)
                    - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t1.breakdown_time, t1.repaired_time)) % 60), ':00') as working_time
from
        (select 
          mom.machinery_operation_master_id,
          mom.assigned_code,
          mom.record_type,
          (case when mom.record_type=1 then time(mom.entered_time) end) power_on_time,
          (case when mom.record_type=2 then time(mom.entered_time) end) power_off_time,
          (case when mom.record_type=3 then time(mom.entered_time) end) breakdown_time,
          (case when mom.record_type=4 then time(mom.entered_time) end) repaired_time,
        from machinery_operation_master mom 
        where mom.location_id = '9' and 
              mom.created_at between '2019-09-17 08:00:00' and '2019-09-18 07:59:00') as t1
```

Comment: i excuted the query but i got this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(6), datediff(second, t1.power_on_time, t1.power_off_time) 
             -' at line 2 0.000 sec

Comment: try again, changed to mariadb

Comment: sir, i got this error,    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(select            mom.machinery_operation_master_id,           mom.assigned_cod' at line 6

Comment: my `from` clause is missing, try now

Comment: sir, i ran this query working fine but not get expected result. actually query returns power on time column value in one row and power off time  value in another row. same as breakdown hours. query returns four records power off time one record, power on time another record and break down time one record and repaired time another record

Comment: i removed those other columns, and will only result the `working_time`, try it again

Comment: only working_time column appeared fine but i got null output.

Comment: seems, you need to check the time entries

Comment: i checked through manual timings then only it gives result. but i have to differentiate  the 1st row of time column and second row of another-time-column from my table records. could you help us

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I think it would look something like this...

```
TIMEDIFF(power_on_time, power_off_time)
```

Which should give you a time value (hours and minutes) already.

More details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

<strike>Assuming MS SQL Server, and that all of your columns are `DATETIME` columns...</strike>

I guess you'd start with getting a `DATEDIFF(hh, power_on_time, power_off_time)` to get the number of hours between them; `DATEDIFF(mi, DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh,  power_on_time, power_off_time), power_on_time), power_off_time)` will get the number of minutes (remainder).

These can be combined and cast to a datetime if you need that.

Then use the same method to calculate 'broken down time' and subtract it from your 'powered on time' - I'm broadly guessing at the details based on your code sample.

Comment: i got this error : Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: That information would be really useful in the question; different DB systems have different flavours of SQL to get the answer that you want.

Comment: sorry, i missed that one, can you give better solution for this question with that db system

Comment: Maybe? But I don't have MySQL to test it.

Comment: sir, how to differentiate time between first row of time column with second row of another time column

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: ok i will repeat again with another way, i want to  calculate total hours from two columns but the two column values are available in two rows

Comment: You would probably get more/better answers (I am running out of time, and not a MySQL expert) if you ask a new question here. That requirement is different to the original question here. Don't forget to add details about what you're using, what you've tried, and try to include an example to help explain your problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).